# Check if text contains more than one @

Tags: regex, string, vb.net

Following code works.

```
    Dim aaa As String = "aa@aa"
    If aaa.Contains("@") Then
        MsgBox("Error1")
    End If
```

Following code doesnt work.

```
    Dim bbb As String = "bb@bbcc@cc"
    If bbb.Contains("*@*@*") Then
        MsgBox("Error2")
    End If
```

So, what is problem with following line?

```
If bbb.Contains("*@*@*") Then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the string `bbb` doesn't contain sequence of characters `*@*@*`.

`String.Contains` doesn't support wildcard characters.

You could use this instead.

```
If Regex.Match(bbb,".*@.*@.*").Success then
    MsgBox("Error2")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use wildcards.

Contains does not support `*` wildcards. Maybe try this?

```
If bbb.Contains("@") And bbb.IndexOf("@") <> bbb.LastIndexOf("@") Then
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.count()` to determine the occurrences of `@` and show the message accordingly.

```
Dim bbb As String = "bb@bbcc@cc"
  Dim cnt As Integer

  cnt = bbb.Count(Function(x) x = "@") 'Number of @ in the string

  If cnt = 1 Then
     MsgBox("Error1")
  ElseIf cnt = 2 Then
     MsgBox("Error2")
  End If
```

---

Note: I assume that OP is looking for occurrences of a character in a string, not the specific pattern to be followed